# Combining two shaders, one with color map, one with a specularity map

Tags: cycles-render-engine, mesh, texturing, materials, uv

I'm trying to add a specularity map to a mesh with a color map shader already on it.  However, when I attempt this, I seem to have to choose between one shader or another (see the `body` and `glossy` shaders in the materials tab in this screenshot of my screen

[image]
<sub>(source: [deepplanet.com](http://www.deepplanet.com/fiddlejs/random/1.png))</sub>

They just toggle back and forth, letting me use one or the other but not both.

So, do I have to remove the color image texture, and then somehow do this another way? Or is there a simple way just to add it? I was trying to follow [this tutorial](http://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/the-secrets-of-realistic-texturing/) but it seemed like a really long way to go about it. Is there a simple, shorter way to do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to use a *mix shader* (or [sometimes an *add shader*](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15458/when-to-use-add-shader)) to combine multiple shader nodes in the node editor.  The mix shader node will combine two shaders based on a given fraction.  The *fac* value determines the amount of the second shader in the output.

For instance the following will result in a 20% glossy (and 80% diffuse) material:
[image]

You can even use something else, such as a map or input node, to control the mix factor variably across the object.

Here I have plugged a specularity map into the factor, lighter areas on the map will receive more gloss, darker areas will receive more diffuse.
[image]

And here I have mixed in another glossy shader using an *input > fresnel* node as a factor, this will make grazing angles even more glossy (which is more realistic).
[image]

*Note: to add a node hit <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and select the node you want to use.*

Comment: So how do I add a mix shader? Can I just add it in the node window?

Comment: @AgentZebra See my last edit.

Comment: Thank you so much! Fantastic in-depth answer. Super helpful!