# How do I subtract an image from specularity of a material in blender?

Tags: texturing, materials

How do I subtract an image from specularity of a material in blender?  If some of you have seen this energy drink tutorial by blender guru can you please tell me how to achieve this effect in blender 2.77 as I cant find any of these properties + I am new to nodes.

[image]

For those who have not seen this tutorial I have attached an image,so please tell how to achieve similar effect?

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/35471/combining-two-shaders-one-with-color-map-one-with-a-specularity-map and  http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13600/how-to-add-a-specularity-map-in-cycles

Comment: a clear explanation here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10595/how-does-fac-differ-with-manual-control-versus-node-control

Comment: some examples of what you can do to combine nodes: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/27475/how-do-you-apply-a-gloss-and-spec-map-on-one-cycles-material/27480#27480

Comment: All those answers were helpful I am glad that a community like this exists .. :)