# How are these Custom Node created?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor

I downloaded a Model from BlendSwap and  when I was looking through materials, I these nodes which I have never seen before.

Examples:

[image]

[image]

How do I create one of these custom nodes?

Comment: Hi, Those are called node groups, I made a post about that a while ago, and above it is another good post by Gandalf: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32989/8262

Comment: maybe this Question can be marked as duplicate, because all info is covered in the linked post.

Comment: @zeffii See [this meta post](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/549/duplicate-answer-vs-duplicate-question).

Comment: @PGmath don't forget [this meta post either](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/896/are-too-many-questions-being-tagged-duplicate)

Comment: are "custom nodes" already a thing with the new blender version 3.1 or 3.2? or are they still group nodes? coz in [this thread](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/268114/how-to-auto-execute-custom-node-tree) someone's trying to make custom nodes, not sure if what he's doing is even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Group Nodes

Those "custom nodes" are really called *Group Nodes*.  You can create a group node by selecting a group of nodes and hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>.  You can see and edit the contents of a group node by selecting it and pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.  Once created, you can add a group node with the <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> add menu under *Group*.

[image]

When editing a group node there are two special nodes. The *Group Input* node allows you to pass information into the group node by plugging its sockets into nodes in the group.  Likewise, the *Group Output* node allows information to pass out of the group node by plugging nodes in the group into its sockets.

You can quickly add inputs and outputs by plugging other nodes into the the empty circle node sockets at the bottom of the input/output nodes.

[image]
*Click to enlarge.*  This is a simple [fake light](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/38979/5705) group node I have created.

You can also add inputs and outputs (as well as remove them, change their names, default values, adjust minimum and maximum values, and change their order) in the <kbd>N</kbd> toolbar under the *Interface* rollout.

[image]

---

Group nodes are very useful for grouping specific node trees you use a lot.  I have created a few node groups I use frequently and included them in the startup file (with [fake users](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32657/what-does-the-f-button-and-2-button-do-materials-tab/32658#32658)) so I have them whenever I need to use them in any project.

Answer (score 2):

In Blender nomenclature these nodes are called [*Node Groups*](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/node_editor/node_groups.html), the symbol below is used to show that. You can think of them as *Custom Nodes* but that term may lead to some confusion because Blender also has *Custom PyNodes* (which are nodes defined in Python).

[image]

Groups of nodes that form a cohesive feature can be placed into a group (a container) and you can give this group *inputs* and *outputs*. This lets you abstract the inner-workings of the node group and keep your main node tree less cluttered.

How to make these node groups is already extensively covered in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/32989/8262) , and [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3456/47).