# Blender Cycles Procedural Cut Aluminum (Cut Aluminium)

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, materials

Photo rendering aluminum extrusion profiles in Blender Cycles.  Tried achieving this using image textures, but doesn't work very well.  It's so reflective, you take a photo at one angle, and your object always has that same reflection, even when you rotate the camera.

How could the same be achieved with procedural texture?

It's very shiny, highly reflective, with saw marks that reflect light at different angles.  Also has a rainbow reflection in the metal at certain angles.

Rainbow part not necessary, but would be a bonus.  I've noticed other metals have similar effect.

[image: Cut extrusion] 
[image: Aluminum saw cut extrusion]
[image: Shiny cut aluminium]
[image: Rainbow look not as important]

Comment: Sounds like normal maps would be handy.  I think Blender has a built in way to do it, but I haven't used it.  There is a normal map plugin for GIMP (that is Windows only), which I have used though, and that gives you the photo powers of GIMP.  Perhaps [a tutorial from Blender Guru](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t4MTnpnahu0) covers what you are looking for?

Comment: Normal maps would add depth to the cut I'm guessing, but not sure how to procedurally generate the lines required for the normal maps.  Want proper lines rather than the typical Voronoi texture that's been stretched out.  Blender Guru used an image made in Photoshop for the lines.  I don't know how to do that in Photoshop/Gimp so I'm hoping to create them in Cycles somehow.

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42133/realistic-aluminum-material-in-cycles

Answer (score 1):

[image: Amelinum]

I could achieve something like this. Remeber to have UV map with *45 degree* rotation, or as much as you want.

I've had better results using PBR shader (not diffuse/glossy mix) from CynicatPro but you can find him on YouTube and whole PBR tutorial here will be too much.

I couldn't do this rainbow reflection at angle but *Noise Texture* mixed with... *Light Path, Camera Data???* could be the thing.

EDIT:

Here's the .blend file:

[image]

Comment: Thank you @LukeD.  I tried but could not quite recreate your look on my part.  Will keep trying though I think you're right.  Will be better with PBR.  Will work on PBR next, then report back.  Thanks.