# Overlay a Shader

Tags: cycles-render-engine, image, shaders

In addition to the Mix Shader node, there is also the Add Shader node. Now if I have two shaders that are the same with small differences, they both get added, and if there are similar areas they become twice as bright. 
I want to overlay one shader with another to the effect that the differences of one shader will be added, but the similarities aren't (so that similar areas don't get brighter). Is this possible, if so, how?

[image]

Comment: Use a Mix Shader for starters, we will need to see your node setup before we can post any more details

Comment: You can control the mix node with a combination of various nodes or a texture using them as a mix factor.

Comment: I don't see how the image would be useful, but here you go: (http://imgur.com/fgpNwaC) I want to overlay the image texture on the bottom with the rest of the node setup. The add shader simply makes all the white areas on my object super duper white since both shaders have a white color in them.

Comment: @meed96 If the image texture is transparent, you should just be able to plug the alpha channel into the factor of the mix shader

Comment: Or you can plug this tecture through color ramp and use it as a mix factor

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/420/difference-between-add-shader-and-mix-shader

Comment: It's not transparent, there's only one layer, and it contains some colors that don't exist in any of the other textures, which is why I'm adding it where it is. I also don't want to alter the current textures, which plugging something into a factor value would drastically effect.

Comment: Yeah but I don't want to change or alter the current state or mix of things, I simply want to overlay it. Mixing or factoring things won't give me that effect. At least not in the pure form I need it in.

Comment: I think you should mix the colors then with MixRGB and plug the result into first diffuse node.

Comment: Again, that would mix the two, I want to overlay one over the other. Mixing them would make changes in areas that would not be affected if there were an overlaying technique.

Comment: What do you mean by "overlay"? assuming  you mean "replace part of the existing image with the new image" You'll need to specify what parts of the image get applied on top of the existing colors and which don't. This is the purpose of an alpha channel, but you can specify your own "alpha channel" by plugging a greyscale map into the mix factor.